# Better/best approach to load huge CSV file into DynamoDb

Tags: node.js, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I have a **huge `.csv`** file on my local machine. I want to load that data in a DynamoDB (eu-west-1, Ireland). How would you do that?

1. My first approach was:

   - Iterate the CSV file locally
   - Send a row to AWS via a `curl -X POST -d '<row>' .../connector/mydata`
   - Process the previous call within a lambda and write in DynamoDB

   I do not like that solution because:

   - There are too many requests
   - If I send data without the CSV header information I have to hardcode the lambda
   - If I send data with the CSV header there is too much traffic
2. I was also considering putting the file in an `S3` bucket and process it with a `lambda`, but the file is huge and the lambda's memory and time limits scare me.
3. I am also considering doing the job on an EC2 machine, but I lose reactivity (if I turn off the machine while not used) or I lose money (if I do not turn off the machine).
4. I was told that Kinesis may be a solution, but I am not convinced.

**Please tell me what would be the best approach to get the `huge CSV` file in DynamoDB if you were me.** I want to minimise the workload for a "second" upload.

I prefer using Node.js or R. Python may be acceptable as a last solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it the AWS way, then data pipelines may be the best approach:

Here is a tutorial that does a bit more than you need, but should get you started:

> The first part of this tutorial explains how to define an AWS Data
>   Pipeline pipeline to retrieve data from a tab-delimited file in Amazon
>   S3 to populate a DynamoDB table, use a Hive script to define the
>   necessary data transformation steps, and automatically create an
>   Amazon EMR cluster to perform the work.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part1.html

Comment: @e-j-brennan Do you know a simple step-by-step tutorial for this workflow? (I've never used EMR, nor Hive and I fear it will take too much time to properly use them)

Answer (score 1):

If all your data is in S3 you can use AWS Data pipeline's predefined template to 'import DynamoDB data from S3' It should be straightforward to configure.